# Select a role when connecting to a PostgreSQL database with JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

How to select a role when connecting to a PostgreSQL database with JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `user` connection property, as described in [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html).